# About Maximal Ideals in R[X] using homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

First I have to find all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{R}$ and all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{C}$. I think these two kinds of homomorphisms can be map by using $f(x) =$ any element in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. But now I have to use these two kinds of homomorphisms to help me find maximal ideals in $\mathbb{R}[X]$. I really have no idea what's the connection between them. Any idea would be appreciated. If my homomorphisms are not correct, please correct me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that an ideal is maximal if $R/I$ is a field, so by the isomorphism theorem, you are looking for the kernels of the homomorphisms which are surjections onto some field.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The kernel of any ring homomorphism into a field must be a prime ideal.

There are essentially three flavors of prime ideals in $\Bbb R[x]$:  the zero ideal, those generated by an irreducible polynomial of degree 1, and those generated by an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$. Your task is to eliminate the first possibility and then sort out what the other two mean.